# How to fix database in rails after deleted migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-migrations

Okay, this is what happened:

1) I needed to add a column to a table but instead of generating the migration I wrote it by hand. The file name I gave it seemed to work okay but didn't have a timestamp so then things went bad.

2) After messing about for ages I updated the schema.rb file so that it looked the way I wanted. Then I reset the database. That was fine but ...

3) When i went to run the migrations the last few had already been run so it thought they were duplicates. So I deleted all the migrations because the schema looked fine and everything was working well.

4) But now it works fine on my local machine but I'm having real issues when I try to deploy to Heroku, which seems to have access to my old migrations and is denying the existence of a table that is clearly there. I've reset a bunch of times.

So, is there some way I can start again with the schema and no migrations and get the system to forget there ever were migrations? Or what if I create two new migrations that contain all the relevant table data?

EDIT: This is what I'm getting from heroku logs. Basically it lets me get to the login page but when I try to sign in this happens.

Started GET "/home" for 89.27.92.12 at 2013-02-19 18:27:01 +0000
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MaterialsController#home as HTML
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "materials" does not exist
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"materials"'::regclass
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"materials"'::regclass
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/materials_controller.rb:11:in `get_materials'
2013-02-19T18:27:01+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum

Comment: hopefully all of your code is under source control and you have backups of your database - the timestamps in the migration file name are stored in a database table that rails creates called 'schema_migrations' when you run db:migrate it checks that table to decide if it should run your migration files - if it exists in the table it will not run - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#what-s-in-a-name - using rails generate migration automatically creates the right filename, but you can do that part manually if desired - in schema.rb you will probably see inserts into schema_migrations

Answer (score 1):

this sounds really messed up!

`PGError: ERROR: relation "materials" does not exist` clearly states that this table is missing in the schema.

you can have a look at the current migration state by looking into the db directly: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * from schema_migrations").map(&:to_s)`

you could also dump the database and have a look localy: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export